# OAuth2 Client should send custom parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, oauth2resttemplate

I'm using spring-security-oauth2-2.2.0  in a spring mvc application. I have my oauth2 token configured with **OAuth2RestTemplate** like this:

```
ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        resourceDetails.setClientId("clientid");
        resourceDetails.setClientSecret("secret");
        resourceDetails.setGrantType("grant-type");
        resourceDetails.setScope("scope");
        resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("myurlé);
        resourceDetails.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
        resourceDetails.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
```

Now I want to add a new parameter within the old configuration and send it to authentication provider. The new parameter is called **resource**. Here is the postman configuration that works perfectly:
[image]

How can I integrate the new parameter to the old token configuration? Which method should I customize?

Comment: Just an fyi, but OAuth2RestTemplate has been deprecated in Spring Boot 2.2.2. You now use the reactive WebClient.

Comment: i'm not using spring boot